# Can glGetError() return the same value several times in a row?

Tags: opengl, error-handling

After having read through and through all documentation I could find, there is still something I'm not sure of concerning glGetError()'s behavior. As per the following paragraph from the [doc](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml):

> If any single error flag has recorded an error, the value of that flag is returned and that flag is reset to GL_NO_ERROR when glGetError is called.

Does this mean that the same value can't ever be returned more than once right after **one single GL call**?

```cpp
glFoo(GL_WRONG_VALUE);

GLenum error = glGetError(); // Returns GL_INVALID_ENUM, for example
error = glGetError(); // Can this *ever* return GL_INVALID_ENUM again?
```

Simply put, does this mean that, should multiple errors *when calling a single function* result in the same error value, only one occurrence is notified?

As an example, glTexParameter*() has 7 possible ways of generating a GL_INVALID_ENUM error flag. Assuming there are 2 or more problems that would make this error arise, does glGetError() only return one GL_INVALID_ENUM?

Comment: I don't understand how you could interpret the quoted statement as saying that. It's talking about what error flag(s) get set, not who set them or how they got set.

Comment: I don't see where I've asked about either who or how. I'm just asking whether more of one occurence of a given error value can be returned, if multiple errors of the same type have been found.

Comment: @Rabbid76: the "duplicate" question was mine as well, and it wasn't about the exact same thing, although they are linked in a way. This is why I made two of them, although I hesitated to do so.

Comment: Your question explicitly states, "Does this mean that the same value can't ever be returned more than once after one single GL call?" And I'm saying that the "this" text doesn't say anything even remotely like that.

Comment: I may have been understanding wrong this then: `the value of that flag is returned and that flag is reset to GL_NO_ERROR when glGetError is called`. To me, this clearly means that one a flag of a given value is returned by glGetError(), the flag is reset and can't return an error until having been set again later. How is it not what it means then?

Comment: It only means that if you start from the assumption that an OpenGL function can only produce a single error. An assumption which doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how you've come to that conclusion, and this was my understanding of that quote while knowing this. I've edited my post about 20min ago to make that point clear.

Comment: That's the only interpretation I can see that would lead you to the conclusion you've reached based on the quote you read. Unless you simply don't understand what "flag" and "value" mean in terms of OpenGL errors.

Comment: I've explained multiple times in multiple different ways, but I can agree on using the wrong terms, although I assume it to be understandable anyway. Feel free to edit the question accordingly if you've understood what I truly meant then.